# how to update a row in postgresql using where and order_by

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have the table below named `transactionCount`:

```
 id | username_id | count | active 
----+-------------+-------+--------
  1 |           1 |     1 | t
  2 |           1 |     3 | t
  4 |           2 |     1 | t
  5 |           3 |     6 | f
```

I want to update the first row where `username_id == 1` of column `count`.

Because of the way the data is structured, i must not used the `id` but rather find a way to ORDER_BY by `username` and update the first row of that user where `active = t` (true)

the final result should be:

```
 id | username_id | count | active 
----+-------------+-------+--------
  1 |           1 |     2 | t               <================ RESULT
  2 |           1 |     3 | t
  4 |           2 |     1 | t
  5 |           3 |     6 | f
```

I have tried the sql query below:

```
UPDATE transactionCount SET count = 2 WHERE username_id = 1 AND active = 'true' order_by id ASC;
```

but it does not seem to work, is it a better way to write that query?

Answer (score 1):

Updates should be performed through primary key fields.

Otherwise your tables can be screwed up since more than one record could match your filtering criteria.

In your case the topmost line you seek might be different than you have earlierly anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the ID to be updated using a subquery. That can then be used in the WHERE condition of your UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE transactioncount 
  SET count = 2 
WHERE ID = (select min(id)
            from transactioncount 
            where username_id = 1 
              AND active = 'true');
```

This assumes that `id` is unique (e.g. the primary key)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE transactionCount SET count=2
WHERE ID =(SELECT id FROM transactionsCount WHERE username_id=1 AND active= ‘true’ ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)
```

This will only take the first id found and update it